# Using Restforce gem with SalesForce API and Oauth 2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rubygems, oauth-2.0, salesforce

I'm trying to use Restforce (https://github.com/ejholmes/restforce) to set up integration with my Rails app to SalesForce's API using Oauth 2.0.

Restforce describes the initialization process as follows:

> Initialization
>
> Which authentication method you use really depends on your use case.
>   If you're building an application where many users from different orgs
>   are authenticated through oauth and you need to interact with data in
>   their org on their behalf, you should use the OAuth token
>   authentication method.
>
> If you're using the gem to interact with a single org (maybe you're
>   building some salesforce integration internally?) then you should use
>   the username/password authentication method.
>
> OAuth token authentication
>
> ```
> client = Restforce.new :oauth_token => 'oauth token',
>   :instance_url  => 'instance url'
> ```
>
> Although the above will work, you'll probably want to take advantage
>   of the (re)authentication middleware by specifying a refresh token,
>   client id and client secret:
>
> ```
> client = Restforce.new :oauth_token => 'oauth token',
>   :refresh_token => 'refresh token',
>   :instance_url  => 'instance url',
>   :client_id     => 'client_id',
>   :client_secret => 'client_secret'
> ```

I have my `client_id` and `client_secret` from the app that was created in SF, but have no idea what other information I need to be putting into restforce.

Does anyone have any experience with this gem? How do I use it to make the original request token request to SF?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to login using Oauth 2.0 first, then provide the tokens to the gem.
I did that using [Omniauth-Salesforce](https://github.com/realdoug/omniauth-salesforce) and after the tokens are handed I instatiate restforce.

The examples in omniauth are using sinatra, please look into [this repo for an implementation using rails](https://github.com/bfagundez/rails-salesforce-oauth-template).

I've [blogged about this as well](http://geekymartian.com/articles/ruby-on-rails-4-salesforce-oauth-implementation/).